# JMeter How to prevent concurrent calls when running stepping thread group

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Ok so I am experiencing an issue where I am supposed to ramp up 10 vusers in 1 minute till it reaches 200 Vusers and hold the load for 60 minutes. However, as it calls 200, it is calling all of them concurrently which is affecting the performance of my test. Right now, I want to call the 200 vusers which each users being called with an interval timing in between instead of one shot concurrent call.

Answer (score 0):

The real users don't hammer the system under test non-stop, they need some time to ["think" between operations](https://medium.com/@malith.jayasinghe/performance-testing-with-a-think-time-64b6b737e3f9).

Well-behaved JMeter test must mimic real user using a real browser with 100% accuracy including [cookies](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), [headers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), [cache](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager), etc.

This "think time" is also uber-important, real users need to read the content of the page before navigating to the next one. If they're supposed to type/write/upload something - they will need even more time.

So in order to accurately simulate this "think time" you need to add a suitable [Timer(s)](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) and configure them properly in order to introduce reasonable delays between requests.